# java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date (facebook date)

Tags: android, facebook, date, parseexception

I am trying to parse "updated_time" and trying to convert it in Date() object. But I am getting following exception.

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2015-10-11T07:21:14+0000"
```

Here is my code.

```
private Date convertStringToDate(String createdAt) {
    Date convertedDate = new Date();
    try {
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");
        convertedDate = formatter.parse(createdAt);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "parse exception while converting string to date for facebook : "+e.toString());
    }
    return convertedDate;
}
```

I Googled but didn't found that much..

Answer (score 1):

`Z` is a timezone, in your date format you have escaped it: `'Z'`. Just try with following date format:

```
"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"
```